# getmod counterpart to chmod in c/c++

Tags: linux, file, permissions, chmod

I need to read the permission bits of a file in linux, and then apply them to another file.  I'm working in C++

I found the chmod() function to set the bits, but is there a getmod counterpart which reads the permissions?

Similarly, I need to read the owner/group and then apply them to another file.  I found the chown() function to set the ownership, but no getown().

Could someone provide a link or simple C/C++ example?

Comment: Search for `stat` function and `stat` structure, or do `man 2 stat`.

Comment: The `stat()` function is for getting most file metadata.

Comment: Yep - stat had all of the info I needed.  If you post as an answer I can accept, or I'll copy to an answers for anyone else looking.